# How can I move element from one window to another [geb]

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am testing web-aplication and I need to move element from one window to another.
Geb has *clickAndHold()* function but that doesn't work for me because offset works only with one window. any suggestions?

```
interact {
    clickAndHold($('#draggable'))
    moveByOffset(150, 200)
    release()
}
```

edit: it is not possible to do it with web driver. you are restricted to only one window and can't go outside of it (draging an object from one window to another), but we managed to do it with `java.awt.Robot`

Comment: You are developing a web application which relies on multiple windows (or tabs) in order to function properly? Would you mind describing the use case by editing your question. If people understand what you want to achieve, maybe you get better responses (or responses at all, as of today).

Comment: I don't think that WebDriver (on top of which Geb is built) allows to perform OS level input events (which dragging an element between two browser windows would be an example of). As far as I understand you can only perform input events within a single browser window. For that particular test you might need to use a different tool, probably `java.awt.Robot` or some framework that uses it underneath.

Comment: @erdi yes its not possible with web driver, we already did it with robot, good conclusion :) this case is closed.